# Solution with initial condition not on the center-manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems

Consider the equations:
$$\dot{x}=Cx+F(x,y), \qquad x\in \mathbb{R}^n,$$
$$\dot{y}=Sy+G(x,y), \qquad y\in \mathbb{R}^m.$$
The eigenvalues of matrix $C$ are on the imaginary axis, and those of S are having negative real part.

Center-manifold theorem says that there is a mapping $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that the set $W^c:=\{(x,h(x)), \,x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$ is invariant for the above set of equations. Further, $h(0)=0$, $h'(0)=0$.

The following reduction is generally used:
$$ \dot{x}=Cx+F(x,h(x)) $$

How to justify this reduction? Are there any theorems which say that the solution with any initial condition $(x_0,y_0)$ not in $W^c$ would reach $W^c$ very quickly (exponentially?) ? Please suggest some references.

Comment: For example, you can refer to [_Methods of Qualitative Theory in Nonlinear Dynamics_ by Shilnikov, Shilnikov, Turaev, Chua](http://www.ni.gsu.edu/~ashilnikov/pubs/part1.pdf). Page 272 (near formula 5.0.6) has an answer for your question.